# Notice (8): Undefined index: From when fetching message response from Google API-PHP Client

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to list user messages in GMail Inbox.

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$opt_param = array('labelIds' => 'INBOX');
$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user, $opt_param);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $messageToGet = ($messagesResponse->messages[$i]->id);
    $message = $service->users_messages->get($user, $messageId);
    $names = array_column($message->payload->headers, 'name');
    $values = array_column($message->payload->headers, 'value');
    $mail = array_combine($names, $values);
    $senderMail = explode("<", $mail['From']);
    if (count($senderMail) == 1) {
       if (strpos($senderMail[0], '@') !== false) {
           $senderName = [];
           $domain[0] = substr($senderMail[0], strpos($senderMail[0], "@") + 1);
       } else {
         Log::info('Sender email could not be found');

         return;
       }
    } else {
       $senderName = [];
           if ($senderMail[0] != "") {
               $senderName = $senderMail[0];
               $senderName = explode(" ", $senderName);
           }
           $senderMail = explode(">", $senderMail[1]);
           $domain = explode("@", $mail['From']);
           $domain = explode(">", $domain[1]);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I tried to fetch 'From' from this `$message` response, it is throwing an undefined index error while fetching response for a message.

```
Notice: Notice (8): Undefined index: From in [File]
```

When I tried to debug the messages response return by the google api-php client, it resulted as below for all the messages

```
[16] => Google\Service\Gmail\MessagePartHeader Object
                        (
                            [name] => From
                            [value] => "Firstname Lastname" <firstname.lastname@gmail.com>
                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
```

For one message, it returned

```
[16] => Google\Service\Gmail\MessagePartHeader Object
                        (
                            [name] => FROM
                            [value] => noreply@<domain>.org
                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
```

Can anyone kindly let me know why the value of [name] key differs from From to FROM? Are there any more formats for the [name] key?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] I dont see anywhere in your code where you are trying to access from or file  this code did not result in this error message.

Comment: Yes, I have added the code part where I access 'From' from the message response.